MouseCursor does't hide using SetSystemCursor
i'm trying to hide cursor while shaking the mouse like the mac OS style
also editing AngryMouse repo to do that funcionality
AngryMouse
but the SetSystemCursor function dows't work after second shake...aka after reusing the function again with the same parameters
is there a way to reslove this problem or an alternative way to do that successfully
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AngryMouse.Animation
{
    public static class CursorManager
    {
        private static IntPtr _originalArrowCursor;
        private static IntPtr _transparentCursor;
        private static bool _isCursorHidden = false;
        private static bool _isInitialized = false;
        private static readonly object cursorLock = new object();

        // Constants for cursor types
        private const uint OCR_NORMAL = 32512; // The standard arrow cursor

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hCursor, uint id);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DestroyCursor(IntPtr hCursor);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetLastError();

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
            {
                lock (cursorLock)
                {
                    // Load the original cursor once for restoration purposes
                    _originalArrowCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(@"C:\Windows\Cursors\macosCursors-s-b\Normal.cur");
                    if (_originalArrowCursor == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error loading original cursor: {error}");
                    }
                    _transparentCursor = CreateTransparentCursor();
                    _isInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr CreateTransparentCursor()
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(32, 32)) // Create a transparent 32x32 bitmap
            {
                return bmp.GetHicon(); // Create a cursor from the transparent icon
            }
        }

        public static void HideCursor()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized) Initialize();

            lock (cursorLock)
            {
                // Hide the cursor only if it is not already hidden
                if (!_isCursorHidden && _transparentCursor != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DestroyCursor(_originalArrowCursor);
                    // Set the cursor to the transparent version
                    bool result = SetSystemCursor(_transparentCursor, OCR_NORMAL);

                    if (!result)
                    {
                        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error hiding cursor: {error}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _isCursorHidden = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Cursor hidden successfully.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cursor is already hidden.");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ShowCursor()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized) Initialize();

            lock (cursorLock)
            {
                // Show the cursor only if it is currently hidden
                if (_isCursorHidden && _originalArrowCursor != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DestroyCursor(_transparentCursor);
                    // Restore the original cursor
                    bool result = SetSystemCursor(_originalArrowCursor, OCR_NORMAL);
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error showing cursor: {error}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _isCursorHidden = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Cursor shown successfully.");

                        // Re-create the transparent cursor to ensure it is available
                        DestroyCursor(_transparentCursor);
                        _transparentCursor = CreateTransparentCursor();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cursor is already visible.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



The code called DestroyCursor() on _originalArrowCursor.  It is no longer usable.

@HansPassant   what should i do the nto let the cursor pointer disappper when hideCursor() and make appear again when showCursor()
